# What operations are allowed when I transform a system of linear equations to another form that maintains the same solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if I row reduce a system of linear equations to a simpler form that involves free variables and variables that depend on those free variables, how do I know these variables in this new reduced system has the same solution set as the original system?

I think the thing I'm having trouble with is understanding what operations are allowed when I transform a system of linear equations to another form that maintains the same solutions. Sometimes I'm worried that the new system has gained or lost solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action should be reversible. This means that when you do a simplification of equation (1) to equation (2), in order for the equations (1) and (2) to mean the same thing, you need (1) to imply (2) and (2) to imply (1). For a very simple example, suppose $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ is given and you want to solve $a + x = b$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. You can check that $a + x = b$ and $x = b - a$ are equivalent because you can get from $a + x = b$ to $x = b - a$ by subtracting $a$ from both sides, and you can get from $x = b - a$ to $a + x = b$ by adding $a$ to both sides.

The technique of "row reduction" solves the equation $Ax = 0$ for $x$ by successively multiplying $A$ on the left by invertible matrices. This maintains the set of solutions $x$ since if $E$ is invertible, then $Ax = 0$ if and only if $EAx = 0$